# Reshape based on subclass with respect to the 2 matched cohorts then do consecutive McNemar tests

Tags: r, match, reshape, chi-squared

I want to

- reshape my matched data (MR vs MS) to be as shown in the attached screenshot; basically with the same columns headings but with the addition of ".1"  that refers to the 2nd set (MS). This is the output of matched 2 cohorts after I sorted them to get the matched pairs (in a column named `subclass`) so I can do McNemar test after that.
- write a function to do McNemar test on consecutive similar groups eg `Gender` vs `Gender.1`, `Smoking_2gps` vs `Smoking_2gps.1`, `Diabetes1.0` vs `Diabetes1.0.1`.etc in MR group versus MS group

Dataset is [here](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZ0tApXZm1HhnDdqvkJbU3oGNGBzpyPSPkFX) (showing sheet 1 for vertical format and sheet 2 for horizontal needed format).

I am thinking about **reshape based on subclass with respect to the 2 matched cohorts MS vs MR in `Status.of.Mitral.Valve` variable**

[image]

**As an amendment**

When I tried to use `mcnemar`, I got `list()`. Here is  `str(df`
**Note: * `wide` dataset is the one that has the horizontal format that we need to do `mcnemar` based on it.

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   124 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ Serial.ID                          : int  39 862 458 581 869 774 888 83 433 655 ...
 $ Status.of.Mitral.Valve             : chr  "MR" "MR" "MR" "MR" ...
 $ Age                                : int  65 60 56 33 50 75 56 79 42 46 ...
 $ Gender                             : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Smoking_2gps                       : int  1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ COPD                               : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Diabetes1.0                        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ Urgent.emergent_procedure          : Factor w/ 2 levels "elective","Urgent/emergent procedure": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ MAE                                : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Postop.Deep.Sternal.Wound.Infection: Factor w/ 1 level "no": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Myocardial.Infarction              : Factor w/ 1 level "no": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ postop.newDialysis                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Takeback.for.Bleeding              : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Discharge.Status                   : Factor w/ 1 level "alive": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ distance                           : num  0.021 0.339 0.193 0.206 0.105 ...
 $ weights                            : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ subclass                           : int  1 2 3 6 7 9 10 11 12 13 ...
```

Comment: check the edit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I use is splitting the data.frame then `cbind`ing it again then changing the `colnames`

```r
df <- df[nzchar(df$Status.of.Mitral.Valve), ]
wide <- do.call(cbind, split(df, df$Status.of.Mitral.Valve))
# run install.packages("stringr") if you don't have stringr installed
colnames(wide) <- stringr::str_replace_all(colnames(wide), c("^MS\\.(.+)$"="\\1.1", "^MR\\."=""))
```

And then we can `lapply` all the vars that are of character type into the McNemar test:

```r
sapply(colnames(df)[sapply(df, is.factor)], function(x){
 tib <- table(wide[paste0(x, c("",".1"))])
 if(any(dim(tib)<2)) NULL else mcnemar.test(tib)$p.value 
}) -> lst

lst <- lst[!sapply(lst, is.null)] 
data.frame(vars=names(lst) , p.value=unlist(lst, use.names=F))
```

It gives the wanted output:

```r
                       vars p.value
1                    Gender       1
2                      COPD       1
3 Urgent.emergent_procedure       1
4                       MAE       1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I tried your code and got this error`df <- df[nzchar(df$Status.of.Mitral.Valve)]`
'Error in `[.data.frame`(df, nzchar(df$Status.of.Mitral.Valve)) : 
  'nzchar()' requires a character vector' then after converting it to character `df$Status.of.Mitral.Valve<-as.character((df$Status.of.Mitral.Valve))
df <- df[nzchar(df$Status.of.Mitral.Valve)]`
'Error in `[.data.frame`(df, nzchar(df$Status.of.Mitral.Valve)) : 
  undefined columns selected'  . Please advice me.

Comment: Thx a lot. Now it works for the first half of my question (Upvoted). Any input regarding `mcnemar`?

Comment: It works manually if I will write variable one by one but I need to do a function as I have a giant number of variables.

Comment: @MohamedRahouma it's in the second part of the answer

Comment: it does give the desired output? can you put `str(df)` in your question

Comment: Thx. I added that to my question. Shouldn't we do that on `wide` dataset instead of `df`?

Comment: @MohamedRahouma I re edited the answer after your edit, and no we should do it on `df` beacause I'm using it to get the `qualitative` vars for the `lapply`

Comment: Very good. Thx a lot (upvoted).The only current drawback that I got a series of p-values without knowing the compare variables names eg Gender then COPD then Diabetes..etc. Any hint?

Comment: @MohamedRahouma simply change the `lapply` to `sapply`, I re-edited the answer

Comment: Great. It works. Accepted as a solution. Is it possible to get the 2 columns containing (variable name and p-value) for included variables) so I can paste them easily into excel or word table?

Comment: Thx a lot (Upvoted!). It works but repeat each variable 5 times with different values. I believe that I should take the latest ones but I wonder if we can fix that in the code itself.

Comment: @MohamedRahouma It gives the correct output see my updated answer

Comment: Thx for your continuous efforts. This is what I got upon retrying the code [link](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZkzapXZSEbQIB3gDzFgSPcz9vSBYQEWmjSV).

Comment: @MohamedRahouma sorry my bad I forgot to edit the `sapply`, check the edit